# How can I use an additional condition by getting data from xls-file input in Pentaho spoon?

Tags: pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon

I have just started learning pentaho spoon steps and have one problem with solving one problem. I need to transform the data from xls-file and convert it do database. The problem is that my input file looks like this: [table-description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMSJ1.jpg)

And I can not find how to solve two problems:

1. For my next step I need to save not only the table itself (Range A8:D11), but also the date (cell A5).  When I am trying to do it in pentaho with Microsoft Excel Input – Step it works only   when I select A8-cell as a start row, but the date is not saved.
2. In Microsoft Excel Input – Step I must always select a start row in order to generate a table and use it in next steps. And I must do it manually, I mean to say that my table starts from A8-cell. In my case I can not always say for sure that the table starts from A8-cell. I know, that the start-cell is that cell, which is in A-Column and has value = “Date”. Microsoft Excel Input – Step will be first step in my kettle because I must get data and change them. That is why I think I can not use before Java Script.

I have not found the solution to these two problems and I do not know if it is possible to make it. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by converting an excel file to database but If you can convert the xls into csv and read that file then you know from which row you need to filter the data. Basically you can use a simple filter step to filter the data when it matches column name. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use two Microsoft Excel Input steps. One step reads the table (A8:D11). The other step reads the date (A5). Then merge the two streams, for example using a Join Rows (cartesian product) step
2. Read everything. Then use a Javascript step with two script tabs. For one of the tabs: Right-click and choose Set start script. Code : `var start = 0;` The other tab should be kept as a transformation script. Pseudocode: `if(FieldA equals "Date") {start = 1;}`. Now you will have an additional field in the stream called `start`. If start equals 0, then you know that your tabular data hasn't started yet, and you can filter out the row.